# MVC 5 Bing Maps example

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, bing-maps

I have been trying to get GMap3 to work on the MVC 5 framework without success, no response in the developer site either. So, I decided to try Virtual Earth a.k.a. Bing Maps

However, that doesn't see to work either, I get an empty map. All I find out there are references to old APIs and things that do not work.

Basically I have this on the HEAD element

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/MapControl/mapcontrol.ashx?v=6.3c">
    </script>
```

and in the body of the view

```
<div id="mymapcontroldiv" style="width:500px;height:500px;position:relative;border:1px;border-color:brown;background-color: #E0E0E0;"></div>


<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var map = new VEMap("mymapcontroldiv");
    var center = new VELatLong(@Model.Latitude,  @Model.Longitude);
    var zoom = 12;
    map.LoadMap(center, zoom, VEMapStyle.Road, false);

    // var pinpoint = map.GetCenter();
    var pushpin = new VEPushPin('1', center, null, 'Panama','ImexCorp S.A.');
    map.AddPushpin(pushpin);

    alert("xx");
    addMarker(@Model.Latitude, @Model.Longitude, @Model.LocationName, 'description');
});



</script>

<script type="text/javascript">


  //declare addMarker function
function addMarker(latitude, longitude, title, description)
{
    var marker = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(latitude, longitude), { icon: "/Content/img/poi_custom.png" });
    map.entities.push(marker);
};

alert("xx");
addMarker(@Model.Latitude, @Model.Longitude, @Model.LocationName, 'description');

</script>
```

The alert() calls I put on the scripts never seem to come up. I only see the map background from the div style, nothing else.

Comment: Try to put the content of your addMarker function inside the document ready (Instead of calling this function, just put the content of it inside the document ready and then remove the other parts). If it is working, then it's more a JavaScript problem rather than a Bing's one. If you remove the block in the bottom, the map should load. Also, consider moving to v7: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427610.aspx

Comment: Well it seems v7 requires an API key that is not bound to anything, it is billable and Microsoft offers no protection from others using your key. I don't think this is the way I want to go.